# EOF in multi-line string error in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was running the following query in PySpark, the SQL query runs fine on Hive

```
spark.sql(f"""
    create table DEFAULT.TMP_TABLE as
    select b.customer_id, prob
    from
    bi_prod.TMP_score_1st_day a,
    (select customer_id, prob from BI_prod.Tbl_brand1_scoring where insert_date = 20230101
    union all
    select customer_id, prob from BI_prod.Tbl_brand2_scoring where insert_date = 20230101)  b
    where a.customer_id = b.customer_id
""")
```

This produces the following error

```
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))
```

Need to fix this error, can't find out why error is occurring.

Comment: I don't think spark supports the implicit join you are doing after `bi_prod.TMP_score_1st_day a,` call. Can you try to make an explicit join, not just use a comma?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend rewriting the code in a more Pythonic way.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1 = (
    spark.table('bi_prod.TMP_score_1st_day')
    .filter(col('insert_date') == '20230101')
    .select('customer_id')
)

df2 = (
    spark.table('bi_prod.Tbl_brand2_scoring')
    .filter(col('insert_date') == '20230101')
    .select('customer_id', 'prob')
)

df = df1.join(df2, 'customer_id')
df.show(1, vertical=True)
```

Let me know how this works for you and if you still get the same error.